# Django Rest Framework ModelViewSet When Posted?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple rest application.

models.py :

```
class Check(models.Model):
    crypted = models.TextField()
    anid = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.anid)
```

serializers.py :

```
class CheckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Check
        fields = ['crypted', 'anid']
```

views.py :

```
class CheckViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CheckSerializer
    queryset = Check.objects.all()
```

urls.py :

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('all', CheckViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Here is what I need : I need to make a code run "when I posted into this page"
How can I provide this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you should override [`create`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) method of `ModelViewSet`:

```py
class CheckViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request):
        # Your code here.
        return super().create(request)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I get things from data which is posted? I tried request.crypted or something like that but it didnt work

Comment: Use [`request.data`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data).